# Avoid for loops in R/ vectorize

Tags: r, arrays, for-loop, vectorization

Suppose I have a vector

```
a <- c(1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1)
```

I want to make a new vector that stores the sum of values before every element after the 3rd element like the vector below:

```
b <- c(8, 13, 19, 20, 22, 23, 24, 25)
```

How can I do this without a for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `cumsum` on the `vector` and index to remove the first two elements

```
b1 <- cumsum(a)[-(1:2)]
b1
#[1]  8 13 19 20 22 23 24 25
```

---

Or another option is `Reduce`

```
b1 <- Reduce(`+`, a, accumulate = TRUE)[-(1:2)]
```

Comment: I've been observing an increase in folks using `Reduce` but I can't figure out the source of the renewed interest.

This is mostly curiosity on my part, because it has never been a part of my practice.

Comment: @alex In `base R`, `Reduce` is one function which can be used for recursive action (without going into `for` loop - although for loop may be more flexible and easier to understand).  Other than that, for cumulative sum, I prefer `cumsum`.  When I edited the `Reduce`, i didn't see the answer from ThomasIsCoding

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option with `Reduce` ([@akrun's `cumsum` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66054128/12158757) is the most concise one, I believe)

```
> tail(Reduce(`+`,a,accumulate = TRUE),-2)
[1]  8 13 19 20 22 23 24 25
```